# Expanding table group pushing other elements away in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have an SSRS Report, that we are going to use as a dashboard, with three charts and a table that expands based on a group.

This is how I want it to look:
[image]

But instead when the table on the right expands it pushes the lower most chart down below the table, like this:

[image]

My question is if there is any way in SSRS to make these two play nice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a quirk of how SSRS works.  To remedy the layout problems, put the left 3 items into a rectangle and the table on the right into a rectangle and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Been banging my head over this